# How to custom format 24 hour Time index in pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file with activity and date-time (similar to fit bit). I want to display every 24 hours of activity in separate lines, which I achieved with a pivot table (I tried using group by unsuccessfully). The problem I can't solve is that the x-axis goes from 00:00 to 13:00. I would like to display between, say, 20:00 to 20:00.

I cannot find any method to reshape the 24 hours to achieve.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Series
from pandas import datetime
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
tkinter.Tk().withdraw()

data=pd.read_csv(askopenfilename(),skiprows=100,usecols=[0,7],header=None)
data.columns=['time','activity']

data['time']=pd.to_datetime(data['time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
data.set_index('time',inplace=True)

data['Date']=data.index.date
#data.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
data['Time'] = data.index.time

data.set_index('Time',inplace=True)
data1=data.pivot(columns='Date',values='activity')
data1.plot(figsize = (13,8), subplots=True, legend=True)
plt.show()
```

I would like to reshape the index time so that the x-axis is not from 00:00 to 23:00 but 20:00 to 20:00

Below is a sample of the current output:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Would like to try it out